# Encountering PLS-00103 errors when trying to call a procedure in function for a package body

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm a beginner in SQL and trying to practice packages and have one with a procedure and function. I made up a procedure that splits a total amount of items into a single pack and leftovers if any. Then I have a function that returns the total cost of ordering items. It uses the procedure to split the items into a pack and leftovers. The pack is multiplied by a given cost, the leftovers multiplied by a set cost, then both are added. I'm having trouble with compiling the function though.

The errors say:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
> following: constant exception   table long double ref char time timestamp
> interval date binary national character nchar The symbol "" was substituted for "=" to continue.
> Encountered the symbol "END" when
> expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure
> subtype type  
> current cursor delete exists prior

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package01 AS

PROCEDURE split 
    ( 
          items       IN    NUMBER, 
          item_pack   OUT   NUMBER, 
          leftovers   OUT   NUMBER 
    ) 
    AS 
    BEGIN 
          DECLARE std_pack NUMBER := 50; 
          
          BEGIN
          IF items <= std_pack THEN 
            item_pack := 1; 
            leftovers := 0; 
          ELSE 
            item_pack := std_pack; 
            leftovers := items - std_pack; 
          END IF;
          END;
    END;

FUNCTION compute_total (
      items_param   NUMBER,
      item_cost   NUMBER
    ) RETURN NUMBER
    AS
      total NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      DECLARE
        another_item_pack NUMBER;
        leftover_items NUMBER;
        leftover_cost := .10;
        
        
        split(items_param, another_item_pack, leftover_items);
        
        
        total := (another_item_pack * item_cost) + (leftover_cost * leftover_items);

        RETURN total;
    END;
    
END package01;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use inner `DECLARE-BEGIN-END` block (in both procedure and function); therefore:

- remove `declare` (this is not an anonymous PL/SQL block),
- relocate `begin`,
- add datatype to `leftover_cost` (and remove colon sign)

Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package01
  2  AS
  3     PROCEDURE split (items      IN     NUMBER,
  4                      item_pack     OUT NUMBER,
  5                      leftovers     OUT NUMBER)
  6     AS
  7        std_pack  NUMBER := 50;
  8     BEGIN
  9        IF items <= std_pack
 10        THEN
 11           item_pack := 1;
 12           leftovers := 0;
 13        ELSE
 14           item_pack := std_pack;
 15           leftovers := items - std_pack;
 16        END IF;
 17     END;
 18
 19     FUNCTION compute_total (items_param NUMBER, item_cost NUMBER)
 20        RETURN NUMBER
 21     AS
 22        total              NUMBER;
 23        another_item_pack  NUMBER;
 24        leftover_items     NUMBER;
 25        leftover_cost      NUMBER := .10;
 26     BEGIN
 27        split (items_param, another_item_pack, leftover_items);
 28
 29
 30        total :=
 31           (another_item_pack * item_cost) + (leftover_cost * leftover_items);
 32
 33        RETURN total;
 34     END;
 35  END package01;
 36  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```